# FadeInImage does not what I expect it to when filtering

Tags: flutter

This might be a bug but I'm not sure.

I'm trying to make a list of users in the app that I'm making. With to the left of all the users a picture of that user. Everything goes well when in loads in. The users that have a picture get them loaded in. The users that don't have one keep a placeholder image. So far so good.

But when I start filtering the records it gets messy. I have a search bar at the top. But when I start searching. All the names are still correctly displayed (the ones that are within the range of the search) but the images don't correspond with the correct users any more.

Please explain if I'm doing something wrong. But this might be a bug because this does not happen when I use the normal Image class. Only when I use the FadeInImage class

Underneath two screenshots to explain my problem. The first screenshot is when I boot the app. The second is after I pressed the button. Notice how the error.jpg url is standing next to the working image in screenshot 2.

[image]

[image]

I made a [small example project](https://github.com/namanix/Flutter_FadeInImageBug) to make it easy to reproduce this.

To reproduce, wait for the top image to load in. The second one will 404 but that is intended so it keeps its placeholder and after that click the button. You will see the 404 url next to the picture that was actually loaded from the web.

Comment: We need the essential details of a question to appear in the questions themselves here, so this is off-topic as it stands. It's OK to offer a GitHub link at the end, but please put an [mcve] in the body of the question.

Comment: Normally i would ofcourse! But this example depends on a asset image in the project. That's not something i can post in a question here i think. That's why i just included the project from github. I couldn't think of a usable example to post with my question.

Comment: You can post images here. Furthermore, I would suggest changing your text so that you do not request that readers download the project and run it - that is not good security practice unless the repo is heavily vetted for malware.

Comment: You're right. You can't know for sure if i havent put any malware in the project. I've added 2 pictures of my problem to the post. I do hope someone can take a look at it for me :)

Comment: Pro tip: when referring to yourself, please use an upper case "I", even if you are posting from a mobile device. This will reduce the amount of repair work that volunteer editors will need to undertake on your material. Stack Overflow is rather different to other sources of assistance on the web - we try to present Q&A as clearly as possible, so that material is useful and readable for future readers.

Comment: You will need to add the relevant piece(s) of code to your question as well, unless you believe that readers can deduce the problem from the images by themselves.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. Still getting used to the standards here